# Parsing csv-like format while ignoring separator within quotes

Tags: python, csv, parsing

I am trying to parse a csv-like file that has a series of keys and values separated by a semicolon (`;`), but am having issues ignoring any semicolons that are surrounded by double quotes. The general format of a line is:

```
key_1 "Value 1"; key_2 "Value 2"; key_3 "Some other value with; possible semicolon"
```

I have tried using the CSV module, but it doesn't seem to properly escape the `;` unless the entire entry is escaped with quotes (both key and value would need to be escaped, which they aren't).

I don't really want to write my own parser (but can if I really need to). I am wondering if there are existing libraries that will handle this? The current code I have tried is:

```
import csv
import io

test_line = '''gene_id "LOC101495167"; product "endo-1,3;1,4-beta-D-glucanase-like"; exon_number "1"; '''

reader = csv.reader(
    io.StringIO(test_line), 
    delimiter = ';', 
    quotechar = '"', 
    skipinitialspace = True,
    quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL
)

for row in reader:
    print(row)
```

Current Output:

```
['gene_id "LOC101495167"', 'product "endo-1,3', '1,4-beta-D-glucanase-like"', 'exon_number "1"', '']
```

Required Output:

```
['gene_id "LOC101495167"', 'product "endo-1,3;1,4-beta-D-glucanase-like"', 'exon_number "1"']
```

or ideally:

```
{"gene_id": "LOC101495167",
 "product": "endo-1,3;1,4-beta-D-glucanase-like",
 "exon_number": "1"}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A regular expression should be enough:

```
import re

test_line = '''gene_id "LOC101495167"; product "endo-1,3;1,4-beta-D-glucanase-like"; exon_number "1"; '''

print(re.findall(r'([^ ]+) "([^"]+)";?', test_line))
```

Output:

```
[('gene_id', 'LOC101495167'), ('product', 'endo-1,3;1,4-beta-D-glucanase-like'), ('exon_number', '1')]
```

This can be used to create the desired final output.